# Neighborhoods in real analysis problem

Tags: real-analysis

Show that if $a,b \; \epsilon\; \mathbb R$, then there exists $\varepsilon$ neighborhoods U of $a$ and $V$ of $b$ such that $U \cap  V = \varnothing $.

I have already defined the sets $V_{\varepsilon}(a):= \{x\epsilon R: |x-a| < \varepsilon\}$ and $U_{\varepsilon}(b):= \{y\epsilon R: |y-b| < \varepsilon\}$ but I don't know how to proceed further. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Carefully choose $\epsilon$ now. Try drawing a picture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Draw a picture. If $\epsilon=\frac{|b-a|}{3}$, it is clear that the intervals $(a-\epsilon, a+\epsilon)$ and $(b-\epsilon, b+\epsilon)$ have no point in common.

If we want to be very formal, suppose to the contrary that $|b-x|\lt \epsilon$ and $|x-a|\lt \epsilon$. Then by the Triangle Inequality 
$$|b-a|\le |b-x|+|x-a|\lt 2\epsilon \lt |b-a|,$$
which is impossible.

Comment: I did as both of you said. I drew a picture so that both intervals have no common point on a number line. I understand this much. My lack of understanding is how do I choose an $\epsilon$. Is it arbitrary? Secondly can you elaborate on the triangle inequality. I am confused as to how you found the contrary statement $|b-x|\lt \epsilon$ and $|x-a|\lt \epsilon$. Your response was very insightful though.

Answer (score 1):

Assume that $b>a$, and let
$$
\varepsilon=\frac{b-a}{2}.
$$
Then
\begin{align}
V_\varepsilon(a)\cap V_\varepsilon(b)&=\big(a-\tfrac{b-a}{2},a+\tfrac{b-a}{2}\big) \cap
\big(b-\tfrac{b-a}{2},b+\tfrac{b-a}{2}\big) \\ &=\big(\tfrac{3a-b}{2},\tfrac{a+b}{2}\big)\cap\big(\tfrac{a+b}{2},\tfrac{3b-a}{2}\big)=\varnothing.
\end{align}

Comment: This is very clear and I can see how at this particular value of $\varepsilon$ there is no intersection between the two sets but does it matter what $\varepsilon$ is? My question may seem vague and I apologize for this but how did you figure you what to choose for $\varepsilon$?

Comment: Anything from $|b-a|/2$ down. I chose $|b-a|/3$ for no particular reason. The intuition is that $x$ cannot be simultaneously close to $a$ and to $b$. If we take (symmetric) intervals of "radius" $\gt |b-a|/2$, they will overlap. But "small" intervals won't.